# Vue.js - Store whole object in data

Tags: javascript, class, vue.js, interface, gamepad

I want to use a gamepad in my vue.js app. So I took some code from the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API) and modified it:

```
data() {
  return {
    gamepads: {},
  };
},
created() {
  this.addEventListeners();
},

methods: {
  addEventListeners() {
    window.addEventListener('gamepadconnected', (e) => {
      this.gamepadHandler(e, true);
    });

    window.addEventListener('gamepaddisconnected', (e) => {
      this.gamepadHandler(e, false);
    });
  },

  gamepadHandler(event, connecting) {
    if (connecting) {
      console.log(
        'Gamepad connected at index %d: %s. %d buttons, %d axes.',
        event.gamepad.index,
        event.gamepad.id,
        event.gamepad.buttons.length,
        event.gamepad.axes.length,
      );

      this.gamepads[gamepad.index] = event.gamepad;
    } else {
      console.log(
        'Gamepad disconnected from index %d: %s',
        event.gamepad.index,
        event.gamepad.id,
      );

      delete this.gamepads[event.gamepad.index];
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this, everything seems to work fine and the console.log logs a whole Gamepad object. But, when I store this Gamepad object in the data, it is stored as the String "[object Gamepad]".

How can I store the real object instead of just the classname?

Comment: `this.gamepads[gamepad.index]` : `gamepad.index` doesn't exist.

Comment: At least, I can see it; so it should exist